# Unix in Tron Legacy

Tags: discussion

They use a Unix system in Tron Legacy. I don't know which one. but I remember  `bin/history`, `whoami`, `ps | grep`, and `login` commands.

Comment: *Some* of us haven't seen it yet :(

Comment: http://jtnimoy.net/workviewer.php?q=178 has a story from one of the effects creators on the commands they used, including `emacs`.

Comment: Put a screenshot. `login` is typed as a command only very rarely, it suggests an old system.